# How to convert an array into a key,value,... array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Item
    [1] => Repaired Wattles
    [2] => Types
    [3] => Non-Wire
    [4] => Estimated Qty
    [5] => 124
    [6] => Actual Qty
    [7] => 124
    [8] => Upload File
    [9] => example.jpg
)
```

I need to add the next value to the previous. I need it to look like this

```
Array
(
    [Item] => Repaired Wattles
    [Types] => Non-Wire
    [Estimated Qty] => 124
    [Actual Qty] => 124
    [Upload File] => example.jpg

)
```

I have something along the lines of this:

```
$array = array(
    foreach($stri as $string) {
        $stri[] => $stri[$val]
    $val = $string + 1;
);
```

I know I am definitely wrong. But right here I'm stuck and don't know how to get my code working as I want it to.

Comment: agree with Rizier123

Answer (score 2):

Write simple `for` loop and increment counter by 2 in each loop:

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) { // increment counter +2
    if (isset($arr[$i]) && isset($arr[$i+1])) { // to make sure if both indexes exists in array
        $result[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
    }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
$arr = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff');
// ...
var_dump($result);

array(3) {
  'aaa' =>
  string(3) "bbb"
  'ccc' =>
  string(3) "ddd"
  'eee' =>
  string(3) "fff"
}
```

---

```
$arr = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee');
// ...
var_dump($result);

array(2) {
  'aaa' =>
  string(3) "bbb"
  'ccc' =>
  string(3) "ddd"
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you've written here? This is currently of minimal use as a learning object

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

First [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) your array into chunks of 2. After this just use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the 0 column as key and column 1 as value. Like this:

```
$arr = array_column(array_chunk($arr, 2), 1, 0);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://3v4l.org/dTkri)

Comment: Please explain the down votes, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but maybe they downvoted because you'll need PHP 5.5 or higher for this.

Comment: You mean they'll need a version of PHP that's supported, rather than an old unsupported version?

Comment: @MarkBaker I mean nothing.

Comment: @MarkBaker I just really hope, that we don't end up with the same with PHP 7 as we did with `mysql_*` where we get tons of question with super old deprecated code. So I hope as soon as PHP 7 is a good stable version, everyone will move on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `array_combine` along with `array_column` and `array_chunk`.

Note: This'll work if the array is perfectly have even number of values

```
$arr = Array('Item','Repaired Wattles','Types','Non-Wire','Estimated Qty',124,'Actual Qty',124,'Upload File','example.jpg');

$final = array_combine(array_column(array_chunk($arr, 2),0),array_column(array_chunk($arr, 2),1));
print_r($final);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/408885)

Comment: You are one thinking step away to get to my code :) But the code works too. People probably have a bad day today, even if it is not Monday.

Comment: Yep you're right  one step away to get to your code. But didn't get to know why its been downvoted.@Rizier123

Answer (score 1):

use the following code

```
echo "<pre>";

$myArr = array('Item', 'Repaired Wattles','Types', 'Non-Wire', 'Estimated Qty', '124', 'Actual Qty', '124', 'Upload File', 'example.jpg');
print_r($myArr);

$total = count($myArr);
$newArr = array();
for($i=0; $i<$total;$i++) {
    $newArr[$myArr[$i]] = $myArr[$i+1];
    $i++;
}

print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(0 => 'Item',
    1 => 'Repaired',
    2 => 'Types',
    3 => 'Non',
    4=> 'Estimated',
    5 => '124',
    6 => 'Actual',
    7 => '124',
    8 => 'Upload',
    9 => 'example'
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);

$a_len = count($a);
$fnl = array();
$i = 0;

while($i<$a_len){
    $fnl[$a[$i]] =  $a[++$i];
    $i++;
}
print_r($fnl);
```